# Strategies for pre-training models for use in tfjs

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras, tensorflow.js, tfjs-node

This is a more general version of a question I've already asked: [Significant difference between outputs of deep tensorflow keras model in Python and tensorflowjs conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61089690/significant-difference-between-outputs-of-deep-tensorflow-keras-model-in-python)

As far as I can tell, the layers of a tfjs model when run in the browser (so far only tested in Chrome and Firefox) will have small numerical differences in the output values when compared to the same model run in Python or Node. The cumulative effect of these small differences across all the layers of the model can cause fairly significant differences in the output. See [here](https://github.com/slothtopus/tfjs-python-node-differences) for an example of this.

This means a model trained in Python or Node will not perform as well in terms of accuracy when run in the browser. And the deeper your model, the worse it will get.

Therefore my question is, what is the best way to train a model to use with tfjs in the browser? Is there a way to ensure the output will be identical? Or do you just have to accept that there will be small numerical differences and, if so, are there any methods that can be used to train a model to be more resilient to this?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on my personal observations. As such, it is debatable and not backed by much evidence. Some things that I follow to get accuracy of 16-bit models close to 32 bit models are:

1. Avoid using activations that have small upper and lower bounds, such as `sigmoid` or `tanh`, for hidden layers. These activations cause the weights of the next layer to become very sensitive to small values, and hence, small changes. I prefer using ReLU for such  models. Since it is now the standard activation for hidden layers in most models, you should be using it in any case.
2. Avoid weight decay and L1/L2 regularizations on weights while training (the `kernel_regularizer` parameter in keras), since these increase sensitivity of weights. Use `Dropout` instead, I didn't observe a major drop in performance on TFLite when using it instead of numerical regularizers.